# Facebook Social Graph - why storing token and secret when login

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I've noticed some people storing token and secret key in a `user` table after a user connects the the app using facebook login.

But I was just wondering, are these values changed constantly or not? Also, are they there to keep the login live or anything?

Comment: they do not change regurlarly

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook API uses [OAuth 2.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OAuth_2.0). Once a user has granted your application privileges to their account, FB sends you an authorization token that your application needs to store. The reason being is that you need to send that token every time you make a FB API request on behalf of that user. FB checks to see if the token is still valid and if it is then it allows the request to be processed (E.g. making a post to the user's wall).

If you look at the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), you will notice the "Access Token" field at the top.  Click the "Get Access Token" button to generate one for your own account so you can make test calls on behalf of yourself.